# How do I add a ViewGroup to another ViewGroup?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've a custom ViewGroup which contains N number of children. Now, I've created another set of ViewGroup. I want to add the second ViewGroup to the first one. How do I do that? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From code:

```
firstViewGroup.addView(secondViewGroup);
```