# How do I put an ImageView, which is not a child, on top of a custom ViewGroup?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to display an image on top of a custom ViewGroup when a condition is met? I've tried this, [How do I add a ViewGroup to another ViewGroup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528220/how-do-i-add-a-viewgroup-to-another-viewgroup), but it does not help, because I dont want to make it a child as the custom ViewGroup has LinearLayout. Is there a way to do this? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `ViewGroup` inside a `RelativeLayaout` as center.

now put `ImageView` inside `RelativeLayout`, you can specify the positions by giving layout margins..